# Excel: Table cells appear to have whitespace after multiline data

Tags: excel, vba

This is a strange one, and I don't know how to word it correctly to find results in searches so even though I would rather not ask here I am going to because I am just baffled.

I have a Table on an Excel Worksheet that I am populating in some code. There is one particular column where I insert some multi-line strings.

When the data gets inserted it displays with what appears to be a bunch of empty lines after the data, ie; The row height is greater than it should be even though it should be auto-fitting.

If I try to double click the row numbers on the left to auto-fit the row it doesn't work, it's as though it thinks there are line breaks after the data in the cell, however, double clicking into the cell to edit it or selecting it and clicking into the formula bar shows there are no blank lines and upon exiting the edit the row will auto-fit and everything is fine.

Ok, even though I have removed hundreds of loc in this handful of functions there is still more code than I would like to post, sorry for that, I just want to show that there is nothing fishy going on anywhere in the code (that I can see).

So, relevant to this code, there are two Worksheets and each has a Table. In the code they are referenced as global `ListObject`'s, `gloMainTable` and `gloSummaryTable`. There is also two `Enum`'s `MainTableColumns` and `SummaryTableColumns` that are just to make maintenance easier if columns get changed around.

`gloSummaryTable` is cleared before we reach this code and we are populating it. We start that by calling into this:

```
Private Sub CreateSummaryTable()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To gloMainTable.ListRows.Count
        ' All sorts of checks and other stuff
        Call CreateTableEntry(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

We go through `gloMainTable` doing checks and when we find a row that we want we pass that row number into `CreateTableEntry()` where we get the data for a new row in `gloSummaryTable`.

```
Private Sub CreateTableEntry(parRow As Long)
    Dim descriptions As String
    Dim projectRows As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    'All manner of irrelevant stuff
    projectRows = GetProjectRowCount(parRow)
    endRow = parRow + projectRows - 1
    descriptions = GetDescriptions(parRow, endRow)
    Call FillTableRow(parRow, descriptions) ' Irrelevant parameters removed.
End Sub
```

Among other things, inside `CreateTableEntry()` we find out how many rows of `gloMainTable` we need to iterate through to build up our data for our new row in `gloSummaryTable` by calling `GetProjectRowCount()`. We pass a start row and and end row into `GetDescriptions()` so that we can build up the string that is causing the issues I am trying to resolve.

```
Private Function GetProjectRowCount(parRow As Long) As Long
    Dim salesforceRef As String
    Dim res As Long
    Dim i As Long

    salesforceRef = gloMainTable.DataBodyRange(parRow, MainTableColumns.Salesforce)
    res = 1
    For i = parRow To gloMainTable.ListRows.Count
        If gloMainTable.DataBodyRange(i + 1, MainTableColumns.Salesforce) = salesforceRef Then
            res = res + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    GetProjectRowCount = res
End Function
```

Here we are checking how many rows after our start row belong to the same data set (checking the salesforce reference number) so that we can perform whatever calculations we need on said range of rows and consolidate the descriptions into a single string in the `GetDescriptions()` function.

```
Private Function GetDescriptions(parStart As Long, parEnd As Long) As String
    Dim res As String
    Dim opt As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    If NoMoreOptions(parStart, parEnd) Then
        res = res & gloMainTable.DataBodyRange(parStart, MainTableColumns.Description)

        For i = parStart To parEnd - 1
            res = res & vbNewLine & gloMainTable.DataBodyRange(i + 1, MainTableColumns.Description)
        Next i
    Else
        opt = GetCheapestOption(parStart, parEnd)
        res = GetDescriptionsOfOption(parStart, parEnd, opt)
    End If
    
    GetDescriptions = res
End Function
```

Here we have created our string of consolidated descriptions that we hand back to the calling code in `CreateTableEntry()` so that they can be passed along with lots of other data not shown here into `FillTableRow()`.

```
Private Sub FillTableRow(_
    parRow As Long, _
    Optional parDescriptions As String = "") ' All irrelevant params removed

    Dim newRow As listRow
    Set newRow = gloSummaryTable.ListRows.Add
    'All manner of irrelevant stuff
    If parDescriptions = "" Then
        newRow.Range(, SummaryTableColumns.Description) = _
        gloMainTable.DataBodyRange(parRow, MainTableColumns.Description)
    Else
        newRow.Range(, SummaryTableColumns.Description) = Trim(parDescriptions)
    End If 
End Sub
```

And then we create our new row in `gloSummaryTable` and populate it (with plenty more than just descriptions)

I just don't know what's happening...

Comment: Is your zoom setting not at 100% ?  I see a few posts suggesting that can throw off auto-fit.  Or see https://superuser.com/questions/389976/how-to-make-excels-auto-fit-row-height-feature-actually-auto-fit-the-row-heig

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah my zoom is at 100% and I tried little tricks to force it to auto-fit like in the post you linked already, to no avail. The only way I could get the row heights to auto-fit was to attempt to edit the cells and on exiting it would display correctly.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok, it is definitely an issue that only affects certain fonts. I am using Liberation Mono (I want monospace so that currency values line up nicely) and when I just selected an affected cell and scrolled through the font list it would resolve itself on certain fonts and go back to oversize on others. I doubt there is a fix for this, I will likely have to choose another font.

Comment: When I've run into similar problems, I have found that first setting the column width to a maximum (eg 255), and then executing `.EntireRow.AutoFit:EntireColumn.Autofit` will correct it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yeah I tried that too, didn't work. It seems to be an issue with particular fonts. What I'm noticing is that when I am scrolling through the fonts they all display different, some appear to have extra blank lines between the lines of text even like Lucida Handwriting. In fact, I just went back and checked right now and even changing the font size seems to make a difference. I was using Liberation Mono at 12pt and when I change it to 11pt it is fine. Seems to be a bug.